# CSS in community article

Tags: community, css, html, articles

We're trying to add styling to an article that will be displayed in the community using css.
Is there a way to do that? We tried the following options but none worked:
1. Adding css between style and /style in the head section of the html.
2. Adding a css file to our documents and referring to it.
3. Writing separate style attribute per each html tag. This solution partially worked. Some of the styling attributes were kept and some disappeared.
Do you have any suggestions/solutions for this issue?
Thanks.